# Bash Check if a Script Ran Successfully (Exit Code not Working)

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following bash script:

```
echo one
echo two
cd x
echo three
```

which fails at the 3rd line as there is no directory named `x`. However, after running the script, when I do `$?`, 0 is returned, even though the script has an error. How do I detect whether the script ran successfully or not?

Comment: Do you want to exit immediately on first error or continue to run other lines in script?

Comment: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2164

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the condition of directory existence in the script statements:

```
[ -d x ] && cd x || { echo "no such directory"; exit 1; }
```

Or put `set -e` after shebang line:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo one
echo two
cd x
echo three
```

Comment: `-e` was the option I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You should end with an exit statement

```
echo one
echo two
cd x
exitCode=$?
echo three
exit $exitCode;
```

Then

```
./myscript
echo $?
```

> 1

Answer (score -1):

I have searched all over with no clear answer to this.  Put simply it doesn't appear to be a native feature in bash.  So I will give you the hard way.

To make a .sh script with multiple commands and you don't know if any will error but you want to check if at least one has. You would need to put a $? at the end of literally every command and redirect it to a text file.  Once it's in the text file you could format it like.

Command1 = 0 Success.
Command2 = 127 Fail.

Or you could just add the numbers to the file run it through some kind of calculator to add everything together and if the output is greater than zero then the command at some point failed. But this won't be overly useful if you want the exact number and there are more than one failure.

UPDATED - This is the best way I could find.

You can put this at the top of your script file to catch any errors and exit if it fails.
set -euo pipefail

Feel free to read the manual pages.